# Error to present view controller centered in iPad iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

In iOS 5 it runs correctly:

```
PinRequiredViewController *pinView = [[PinRequiredViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"PinRequiredView" bundle:nil];

            UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pinView];

            // show the navigation controller modally
            navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            navController.modalInPopover = NO;
            navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

            [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];

            navController.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250);

            navController.view.superview.center = self.view.window.center;
```

But not working fine in iOS6, the view does not stay centered in the screen, both portrait and landscape.
Any solutions?

Thanks!! :)

Comment: I have the same problem and cant solve it. Used to work fine before iOS 6.

Comment: @Javi_576 What exactly is the issue here?  Questions that say "not working" are not a thorough description of the issue.  Are you saying that it does not present at all?

Comment: No, the view is centered in iOS5 with this code, but no in iOS6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it'll work if you remove the `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` transition style and use one of the other transition styles instead.

Seems like it's a bug with `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`.

Comment: Thanks men! It's a bug because I used another `UIModalTransitionStyle` and run's OK! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the completion: in your presentViewController:

```
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{
        navController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250);}];
```

This will make it work with `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal`.

Comment: This is a step in the right direction, but the modal animation is the incorrect size until after the animation completes. The end result is jarring.

Comment: On iOS6 the  navCon.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPopupsWidth, kPopupsHeight) after presentViewController:animated:completion: used to work, but not anymore on iOS7(Beta 5). The view is resized, but not centered... On completion works, but an animation ugly as hell!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can set the frame of the superview to whatever you want but the origin will not be changed. That's the reason why it doesn't stay centered.

It looks like Apple restricted this on purpose in iOS6

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding with **UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal**, the only wayout is by first presenting view without animation, setting the center point, after that  in next line dismissing it and than again showing it with animated:yes. Like below.....

```
[self presentViewController:navController animated:NO completion:nil];

CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2);
navController.view.superview.center = centerPoint;
[navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded with the following:

```
aboutViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
aboutViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

CGRect aboutSheetFrame = aboutViewController.view.frame;
[self presentViewController:aboutViewController animated:YES completion:^{
        aboutViewController.view.superview.bounds = aboutSheetFrame;
        }];
aboutViewController.view.superview.bounds = aboutSheetFrame;
```

Use of `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` transition is still buggy on ios 6.1 beta 2.
`aboutSheetFrame` is to avoid sizes hardcoding.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in viewDidAppear instead of viewDidLoad. And you're sorted !

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7 try this:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
    //Make the modal bigger than normal
    navigationController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 650);
}];
```

The animation will look ugly so I would recommend adding an animation to improve it:

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        //Make the modal bigger than normal
        navigationController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 700, 650);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}];
```

Also remember that you will need to set the frame of the navigationControllers view in the viewDidAppear for the content to be the correct size.