# How to fix the UIModalTransitionstyle issue on ios6?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios6, uimodaltransitionstyle

I am using the following code for UIModalTransitionStyle view in my application when i click the button

```
 InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];


infoViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self.presentedViewController presentViewController:infoViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

its worked perfecly in ios5 but i update the application ios6 it not worked. How can I handle this issue

Comment: Please give more exact details on what is occurring, in what way it is not working, anything showing in your debugger, etc.  Otherwise nobody will be able to help you with your question.

Comment: @MattMc its worked ios5 perfectly only in ios6 transition style not worked

Comment: Meaning what? The transition style isn't what you want it to be?  It doesn't present at all?  What is "self.presentedViewController"?  What object is your code in?  When are you calling this?  These are things that I mean by "more exact details".

Comment: @MattMc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563798/error-to-present-view-controller-centered-in-ipad-ios-6 same type of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, tested in iOS 6.0 simulator.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://videoURL"]];
    self.moviePlayerController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self presentViewController:self.moviePlayerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Since the URL is invalid, the MPMoviePlayerViewController will just endlessly flip back and forth, but the point is that it works.